# How to find all external calls to an application in erlang

Tags: erlang

How does one find all calls to an Erlang application from other applications? That is, if an application someapp has modules someapp_mod_a and someapp_mod_b where someapp_mod_a calls someapp_mod_b, how to find all calls to someapp while excluding the above-mentioned intra-application call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

xref (http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/tools/xref_chapter.html) allows to do this by executing the following query:

```
xref:q(s, "E || someapp | (A - someapp)").
```